# How to run only a test suite with the connectedAndroidTest command

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, circleci

I am having problems with timeouts running my UI tests in circle ci since the command connectedAndroidTest is taking more than 10 minutes to run.

So I am trying to split them into test suits and run each suite at a time.

I found how to create suites for my android tests here: https://developer.android.com/reference/junit/framework/TestSuite.html

But I can't find how to run them with the connectedAndroidTest command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not found any way to execute the TestSuite, but I found two other options to solve my timeout problems with the circle ci tests:

- Run tests by package:

`./gradlew app:connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.package=<package>`

- Run tests by type:

`./gradlew connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.size=<small|medium|large>`

You need to add @SmallTest, @MediumTest, @LargeTest to your test classes or methods to split them into the groups and avoid hitting a timeout.

Another option that I found was to change the timeout of the command:

```
- ./gradlew app:connectedCheck -PdisablePreDex:
    timeout: 1800
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to @jonathanrz answer:

- Run tests by class:

`./gradlew app:connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class= com.example.app.MyTestClass`

- Run tests by method:

`./gradlew app:connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class= com.example.app.MyTestClass#myTestMethod`

Btw: You can add further arguments to your tests by adding:

`-Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.foo="My\ Extra\ Info`

Just note how you have to escape spaces here if they exist